# Table of coin parameters

Tags: address, altcoin, satoshi, port

What are the

- P2P network magic bytes
- P2PKH version byte
- P2SH version byte
- Private key version byte
- P2P Port
- RPC Port
- Atomic units per coin (100,000,000 for bitcoin)

for Bitcoin, Bitcoin testnet, and common altcoins?